# Message not being deleted when coding telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to delete messages with the words "Escrow Wallet" in my telegram bot. I have the code to delete a message but when I try to use it, the bot isn't deleting the message. My code so far is:

```
import os
import time
import telebot
import re

my_secret = os.environ['API_KEY']
API_KEY = os.getenv('API_KEY')

bot = telebot.TeleBot(my_secret)


@bot.message_handler(commands=["auth"])
def auth(message):
      time.sleep(2 * 60)
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, " @log2, the funds have been deposited in the escrow wallet. You can go ahead and deliver the product(s) to the buyer. When @Audio is satisfied, he can paste /release into the chat or /contact in case of a dispute\n\n  The seller can also /refund the buyer!")



@bot.message_handler(commands=["balance"])
def balance(message):
      
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, " ESCROW WALLET\n\n Wait for the balance to show up here, then continue with the deal. The funds will show up after 1 blockchain confirmation.\n\n BALANCE: 0.00775835 BTC [$1730.94]")
    
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: re.search(r'escrow wallet', message.text, re.IGNORECASE))
def delete_escrow_wallet_message(message):
        bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

Can someone check the code where I tried to delete any message with the words "escrow wallet". I think something is wrong there. I want to delete any message with the words escrow wallet using the bot.

Answer (score 0):

Telebot doesn't use all handlers at once. If your message is intercepted by one handler, the second one will not receive the message. Try moving `delete_escrow_wallet_message` upper.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a message that contains "escrow wallet," you can't delete it directly inside a message handler. Instead, you should flag the message for deletion and then delete it outside in the main program loop.

```
def delete_marked_messages():
    for message in messages_to_delete:
        try:
            bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
        except telebot.apihelper.ApiException as e:
            print(f"Error deleting message: {e}")
    messages_to_delete.clear()
```